# Use tfs in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, tfs

I recently installed android studio 1.2.2 and want to use tfs as my version control.

In android studio's plugins I found [JetBrains TFS Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=webStorm) But when I install that it's turn to red and after many searches it seem's this plugin not working in android studio.

I know there is lots of other version control that android studio can use them but we use tfs for all other our projects so we want to use tfs for this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JetBrains TFS Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=webStorm) is just work on [IntelijIdea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) because it is not a free plugin. So we decide to use eclipse beacause it has a nice `tfs` plugin.